# PyAudio IOError: [Errno Invalid input device (no default output device)] -9996

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

I am attempting to run a simple python file that uses pyaudio to record input.  However whenever I run this file I end up with this error.  I had it working once and I have no idea what changed.  I have tried

```
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print(pa.get_device_count())
0
```

So I am seeing that it does not detect any valid devices.  Is there anyway to specify to pyaudio/portaudio where to look for my input devices.  I am running elementary os freya.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I accidentally ran

```
# p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# ...
p.terminate()
```

and then tried to open another stream.

Answer (score 3):

Silly as it may seem, I had the same error, and I have been thinking: Drivers missing? Audio board missing? Microphone turned off by the OS?

No, I only needed to plug in the microphone (the actual, material, device).

Answer (score 0):

The code you paste works on my machine: I get 24. 
Try to reinstall your audio drivers, I'm assuming you are sure you have a working device connected.